# How can I stop my button from pressing automatically?

Tags: javascript, html

I have assigned an onclick function to a button on my page. However when I open the page, it already automatically presses, and it messes up the numbers.

Edit: In the meantime the title issue has been fixed. The problem now lies at images.

```js
var pt;
var d1;
var d2;
var bet;
var betInt;
var guess;
var money = 100;
var moneyInt;
var rroll;
var ptprogress = [];


 function roll() {
        guess = document.getElementById("pGuess").value;
        bet = document.getElementById("pBet").value;
        betInt = parseInt(bet);
        money = document.getElementById("money").innerHTML;
        moneyInt = parseInt(money);
        ptprogress.push(moneyInt);
   
d1 = dicerange(1, 7) - 1;
d2 = dicerange(1, 7) - 1;
rroll = d1 + d2; 
   
        if (moneyInt < bet) {
          alert("Don't think so, buddy. Earn a few more bucks first.");
          return;
        }
        if(bet <= 0) {
            alert("No bets below zero buddy, name a number!");
            return;
        }
        if (guess == rroll) {

          document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = moneyInt + 2 * betInt;
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Hmph, you won this one...";
        } 
        else {
          document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = moneyInt - betInt;
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Tough luck mate";

        }
        if (moneyInt === 0) alert("Congratulations my man, you have absolutely nothing left.");
      }


function dicerange(min, max) {
  return Math.ceil(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function getDice() {

  switch (d1) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById("die1img").src = "http://tlangevoort.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/Projects/Eindopdracht/reddie1md.png";
      break;

    case 2:
      document.getElementById("die1img").src = "http://tlangevoort.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/Projects/Eindopdracht/red-die-2-md.png";
      break;


    case 3:
      document.getElementById("die1img").src = "http://tlangevoort.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/Projects/Eindopdracht/red-die-3-md.png";
      break;


    case 4:
      document.getElementById("die1img").src = "http://tlangevoort.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/Projects/Eindopdracht/red-die-4-md.png";
      break;


    case 5:
      document.getElementById("die1img").src = "http://tlangevoort.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/Projects/Eindopdracht/red-die-5-md.png";
      break;

    case 6:
      document.getElementById("die1img").src = "http://tlangevoort.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/Projects/Eindopdracht/red-die-6-md.png";
      break;
  }

  switch (d2) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById("die2img").src = "http://tlangevoort.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/Projects/Eindopdracht/red-die-1-md.png";
      break;

    case 2:
      document.getElementById("die2img").src = "http://tlangevoort.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/Projects/Eindopdracht/red-die-2-md.png";
      break;


    case 3:
      document.getElementById("die2img").src = "http://tlangevoort.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/Projects/Eindopdracht/red-die-3-md.png";
      break;


    case 4:
      document.getElementById("die2img").src = "http://tlangevoort.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/Projects/Eindopdracht/red-die-4-md.png";
      break;


    case 5:
      document.getElementById("die2img").src = "http://tlangevoort.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/Projects/Eindopdracht/red-die-5-md.png";
      break;

    case 6:
      document.getElementById("die2img").src = "http://tlangevoort.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/Projects/Eindopdracht/red-die-6-md.png";
      break;
  }

}

function restart() {
  document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "100";
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("pBet").value = "";

  document.getElementById("die1img").src = "";
  document.getElementById("die2img").src = "";
}
```

```css
html {
  background-image: url(http://orig00.deviantart.net/a35e/f/2014/137/1/c/casino_card_background_wallpaper_hd_1920x1080_by_giozaga-d7intx0.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.diceposition {
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  color: white;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.emptydie {
  width: 512;
  height: 512;
}

.die1 {
  border: solid;
  border-style: inset;
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 7.5%;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.die2 {
  border: solid;
  border-style: inset;
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 7.5%;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.button1 {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #8b0002;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 30px 30px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  background-color: #fd4140;
}

.button2 {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #8b0002;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 40px 40px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  background-color: #fd4140;
}

.holder {
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 12%;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #8b0002;
  padding: 12px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #666666;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: url('https://www.spreadshirt.com/image-server/v1/designs/12491917,width=178,height=178/poker-suit-diamond.png') no-repeat 97% 50% #ffffff;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.input {
  width: 12%;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 12px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #8b0002;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://tlangevoort.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/Projects/Eindopdracht/CSS%20Eindopdracht">

</head>

<body>
 <div class="die1">
  <img id="die1img" src="">
 </div>
 <div class="die2">
  <img id="die2img" src="">
 </div>
 <center>
  <p id="money" style="margin-left: 0px; border-style: solid; border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px; width: 100px; height: 40px; padding-top: 15px; background-color: #fd4140; border-color: #8b0002; color: #ffffff; text-weight: bold; font-size: 25px;">100</p>
 </center>
 <br>
 <div style="margin: auto;">

  <div class="holder">
   <input class="input" type="text" id="pBet">
  </div>
  <br>


  <div class="holder">
   <select class="dropdown" id="pGuess">
   
   <option value="1">Pick a bet</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12</option>
  </select>
  </div>

  <br>
  <button type="submit" class="button1" onclick="roll()">Roll those dice!</button>


  <div class="holder">
   <button type="submit" class="button2" onclick="restart()">Redraw</button>
  </div>
  <div class="holder">

   <p style="family-font: Verdana; color: white; font-size: 20px" id="output">
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script src="http://tlangevoort.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/Projects/Eindopdracht/JS%20Eindopdracht"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: cant verify this, also your code contains error, function brackets are not closing

Comment: I closed everything in the total of it. I can send the entire thing if that makes things easier?

Comment: Some questions: 1) How come your first if statement is not closed? 2) Where else in your code do you see Roll() ? 3) Not a question, but please make a smaller version of your code eliminating most of the functionality of your program. It should contain just the button and function and should be enough to demonstrate the problem. Then give us your entire code. If the smaller version does not demonstrate the problem, then try adding a bit at a time until you find out the section of your code that is causing the problem.

Comment: sorry there are not closed brackets my friend

Comment: okay let me add more of it to clarify

Comment: If you get rid of everything inside of your Roll() function except for a single `alert` line, do you still encounter the problem of the button activating?

Comment: at least it would make sense, that if you make a code snippet, that it works as you describe

Answer (score 0):

The code that You've pasted in has some type errors. There are two missing parentheses, one of which is the enclosing one for the whole `Roll` function. After correcting the code it behaves normal, therefore the `Roll` function is activated only after a click on the button.

I would advise not naming regular functions with capital letter. Only constructor functions in object oriented programming should be named with first letter capitalized. All the other functions should start with lowercase, f.e. `roll` or `rollDice`. Not `Roll` or `RollDice`.

Here's the corrected code that's working for me as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Button function</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type = "submit" class="button1" onclick="roll()">Roll those dice!</button>
    <script>
      function roll() {
        guess = document.getElementById("pGuess").value;
        bet = document.getElementById("pBet").value;
        betInt = parseInt(bet);
        money = document.getElementById("money").innerHTML;
        moneyInt = parseInt(money);
        ptprogress.push(moneyInt);
        if (moneyInt < bet) {
          alert("Don't think so, buddy. Earn a few more bucks first.");
          return;
        }
        if(bet <= 0) {
            alert("No bets below zero buddy, name a number!");
            return;
        }
        if (guess == roll) {

          document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = moneyInt + 2 * betInt;
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Hmph, you won this one...";
        } 
        else {
          document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = moneyInt - betInt;
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Tough luck mate";

        }
        if (moneyInt === 0) alert("Congratulations my man, you have absolutely nothing left.");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
var pt;
var d1;
var d2;
var bet;
var betInt;
var guess;
var money = 100;
var moneyInt;
var rroll;
var ptprogress = [];

 function roll() {
    guess = document.getElementById("pGuess").value;
    bet = document.getElementById("pBet").value;
    betInt = parseInt(bet);
    money = document.getElementById("money").innerHTML;
    moneyInt = parseInt(money);
    ptprogress.push(moneyInt);
    if (moneyInt < bet) {
      alert("Don't think so, buddy. Earn a few more bucks first.");
      return;
    }
    if(bet <= 0) {
        alert("No bets below zero buddy, name a number!");
        return;
    }

      d1 = dicerange(1, 7) - 1;
      d2 = dicerange(1, 7) - 1;
      rroll = d1 + d2; 
      console.log(rroll);
    if (guess == rroll) {

      document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = moneyInt + 2 * betInt;
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Hmph, you won this one...";
    } 
    else {
      document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = moneyInt - betInt;
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Tough luck mate";

    }
    if (moneyInt === 0) alert("Congratulations my man, you have absolutely nothing left.");
  }

function dicerange(min, max) {
  return Math.ceil(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function getDice() {

  switch (d1) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById("die1img").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/9/u/S/1/o/A/red-die-1-md.png";
      break;

    case 2:
      document.getElementById("die1img").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/N/e/8/O/Z/G/red-die-2-md.png";
      break;


    case 3:
      document.getElementById("die1img").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Y/3/S/S/N/8/red-die-3-md.png";
      break;


    case 4:
      document.getElementById("die1img").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/T/1/G/i/B/E/red-die-4-md.png";
      break;


    case 5:
      document.getElementById("die1img").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/p/N/w/Z/Q/C/red-die-5-md.png";
      break;

    case 6:
      document.getElementById("die1img").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/O/r/n/M/N/g/red-die-6-md.png";
      break;
  }

  switch (d2) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById("die2img").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/9/u/S/1/o/A/red-die-1-md.png";
      break;

    case 2:
      document.getElementById("die2img").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/N/e/8/O/Z/G/red-die-2-md.png";
      break;


    case 3:
      document.getElementById("die2img").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Y/3/S/S/N/8/red-die-3-md.png";
      break;


    case 4:
      document.getElementById("die2img").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/T/1/G/i/B/E/red-die-4-md.png";
      break;


    case 5:
      document.getElementById("die2img").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/p/N/w/Z/Q/C/red-die-5-md.png";
      break;

    case 6:
      document.getElementById("die2img").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/O/r/n/M/N/g/red-die-6-md.png";
      break;
  }

}

function Restart() {
  document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "100";
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("pBet").value = "";

  document.getElementById("die1img").src = "http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/epicrapbattlesofhistory/images/4/4f/White_square.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140413154605";
  document.getElementById("die2img").src = "http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/epicrapbattlesofhistory/images/4/4f/White_square.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140413154605";
}
```

```css
html{
background-image: url(http://orig00.deviantart.net/a35e/f/2014/137/1/c/casino_card_background_wallpaper_hd_1920x1080_by_giozaga-d7intx0.jpg);
background-size: cover;
}

.button1 {
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
 border:2px solid #8b0002;
 color: #ffffff;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 30px 30px;
 font-family: Verdana;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding: 15px 25px;
 background-color: #fd4140;
}

.button2 {
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
 border:2px solid #8b0002;
 color: #ffffff;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 40px 40px;
 font-family: Verdana;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 6px 20px;
  background-color: #fd4140;
}

.holder {
  text-align: center;
  
}

.dropdown {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 12%;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #8b0002;
  padding: 12px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #666666;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: url('https://www.spreadshirt.com/image-server/v1/designs/12491917,width=178,height=178/poker-suit-diamond.png') no-repeat 97% 50% #ffffff;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.input {
  width: 12%;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 12px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #8b0002;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://tlangevoort.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/Projects/Eindopdracht/CSS%20Eindopdracht">
 
</head>

<body>
 <div class="textactual" style="border-color:#FFFFFF;  
                 width: 90%;
               
                 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
                 color: white;
                 margin-top: 2%;
                 margin-left: 5%;
                 ">
  <div style="border: solid; border-style: inset; width: 512px; height: 512px; background-color: white; float: left; margin-left: 7.5%; margin-top: 100px;" id="diceleft">
   <img style="width: 512; height: 512;" id="die1img" src = "http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/epicrapbattlesofhistory/images/4/4f/White_square.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140413154605">
  </div>
  <div style="border-style: inset; width: 512px; height: 512px; background-color: white; float: right; margin-right: 7.5%; margin-top: 100px;" id="diceright">
   <img style="width: 512; height: 512;" id="die2img" src = "http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/epicrapbattlesofhistory/images/4/4f/White_square.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140413154605">
  </div>
  <center>
   <p id="money" style="margin-left: 0px; border-style: solid; border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px; width: 100px; height: 40px; padding-top: 15px; background-color: #fd4140; border-color: #8b0002; color: #ffffff; text-weight: bold; font-size: 25px;">100</p>
  </center>
  <br>
  <div style="margin: auto;">

   <div class="holder">
    <input class="input" type="text" id="pBet">
   </div>
    <br>
   

   <div class="holder">
    <select class="dropdown" id="pGuess">
   
   <option value="1">Pick a bet</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12</option>
  </select>
   </div>

   <br>
    <button type = "submit" class="button1" onclick="roll()">Roll those dice!</button>
   
   
   <div class="holder"> 
  <button type = "submit" class="button2" onclick="Restart()">Redraw</button>
   </div> 
   <div class="holder">
    
   <p id="output">
   </p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="http://tlangevoort.informatica.bc-enschede.nl/Projects/Eindopdracht/JS%20Eindopdracht"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Okay I tried what you recommended, and it is now indeed fixed, thank you. However, it is still not quite working as intended, as the die images do not change, and as such it is not possible to win.

Comment: Please send the whole code and HTML markup for dice rolling and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Alright, there. Also I renamed 'Restart' to 'restart'.

Comment: The function to random generate the roll is positioned after the check if the roll is the same as the guess, therefore it always points to loss, since ```rroll``` is always ```undefined``` I console.logged the ```rroll``` to be sure that the result is the same as shown in the app status on the page. Also, there was ```roll``` variable being compared to ```guess```. I assume You meant ```rroll``` variable that is everywhere else, so I've changed it to ```rroll```. I've updated the ```roll``` function in my answer to show the changes made.

Comment: I had also noticed this, and I have made changes accordingly. The currency now works as intended. The only thing missing now is the images. I have no idea what causes the images to not appear

Comment: I think it has to do with the images itself, since when going to the image address it show a blank image. F.e. http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/epicrapbattlesofhistory/images/4/4f/White_square.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140413154605 I would advise to use local images at least for developing the app to make sure it's always available and avoid some headaches and also to move all styles to a css file or at least to the head of the document in <style> tags as styling inside HTML elements is a bad practice.

Comment: Alright, I have changed it to local images, and shoved as much CSS into a separate sheet as I could before having it crash. The images still do not update and I don't know why so I'll post my updated code.